# Running an .exe on Android using Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, process.start

I'm trying to build an Android app using Xamarin.Forms based on a Windows Desktop Application that I programmed. In that program, I ran an .exe using `Process.Start()`, but it doesn't seem to work for Android. Google wasn't a great help, so now I'm wondering:

Is it even possible to run an .exe on Android? If so, whats the best way to do it?

Comment: The closest you can get to this is Uno Platform, which is designed to port UWP apps to mobile devices. Unfortunately, Microsoft never endorsed Uno, so it has a relatively small community of users.

Comment: are you trying to run a **windows executable** on Android? If so, no that will not work.  If you are trying to do something else you really need to explain more clearly

Comment: @Jason Yes thats what I'm trying to do. Thanks for the answer